# Haskell - Pattern matching with data types

Tags: haskell

I have a data type and function like this:

```
data Expr = Num Int | Add Expr Expr | Mult Expr Expr | Neg Expr | If Expr Expr Expr deriving (Show, Read)

prettyPrint :: Expr -> IO () 
prettyPrint expr = prettyPrint' expr 0


prettyPrint' :: Expr -> Int -> IO () 
prettyPrint' (Num x) i = putStrLn $ concat (replicate i "    ") ++ "Num " ++ show x

prettyPrint' (Add x y) i = do
    putStrLn $ concat (replicate i "    ") ++ "Add" 
    prettyPrint' x (i+1) 
    prettyPrint' y (i+1) 

prettyPrint' (Mult x y) i = do
    putStrLn $ concat (replicate i "    ") ++ "Mult" 
    prettyPrint' x (i+1) 
    prettyPrint' y (i+1) 

prettyPrint' (Neg x) i = do
    putStrLn $ concat (replicate i "    ") ++ "Neg" 
    prettyPrint' x (i+1) 

prettyPrint' (If x y z) i = do 
    putStrLn $ concat (replicate i "    ") ++ "If" 
    prettyPrint' x (i+1) 
    prettyPrint' y (i+1) 
    prettyPrint' z (i+1)
```

In the function I am using pattern matching. The problem is that their is a lot of reuse of code. For example, the case for `Mult` and `Add` is basically the same code. Same goes for `Num` and `Neg`. Is there a way to write this based on how many variables the expression have? Like one for `Num` and `Neg`, since they have only one variable. One case for `Mult` and `Add`, since they have two variables. And a last case for `If`, since that expression have three variables.

NOTE:

I landed on this answer, I think it's a better solution than I started with:

```
prettyPrint :: Expr -> IO () 
prettyPrint expr = putStrLn (prettyPrint' 1 expr)

prettyPrint' :: Int -> Expr -> String
prettyPrint' i (Num x) = "Num " ++ show x 
prettyPrint' i expr = 
    let indent x = concat (replicate i "    ") ++ x 
        (op, args) = case expr of
            Add x y  -> ("Add",  [x,y])
            Mult x y -> ("Mult", [x,y])
            Neg x    -> ("Neg",  [x])
            If x y z -> ("If",   [x,y,z])
    in intercalate "\n" (op : map (indent . prettyPrint' (i + 1)) args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would stay out of the IO monad for as long as possible. Have `prettyPrint'` return a string to be printed.

```
prettyPrint :: Expr -> IO ()
prettyPrint = putStrLn . prettyPrint'
```

Now, the only job of `prettyPrint'` is to create a (possibly multiline) string to be printed. For numbers, that's easy: just use the `show` instance.

```
prettyPrint' :: Expr -> String
prettyPrint' e@(Num _) = show e
-- or, ignoring the Show instance for Expr altogether
-- prettyPrint' (Num x) = "Num " ++ show x
```

For the rest, there is a pattern:

1. Identify the constructor
2. Identify its arguments
3. Join the constructor name and its pretty-printed arguments with newlines. Each argument will be indented one level relative to its operator; the recursion will take care of multiple levels of indentation.

That will look like

```
prettyPrint' expr = let indent x = "    " ++ x
                        (op, args) = case expr of
                           Add x y  -> ("Add",  [x,y])
                           Mult x y -> ("Mult", [x,y])
                           Neg x    -> ("Neg",  [x])
                           If x y z -> ("If",   [x,y,z])
                    in intercalate "\n" (op : map (indent . prettyPrint') args)
```

As an example, consider what `prettyPrint'` will do with the expression `Add (Num 3) (Num 5)`. First, it sets `op` to `"Add"` and `args` to `[Num 3, Num 5]`. Next, it maps `indent . prettyPrint'` over the argument list, to get `["    Num 3", "    Num 5"]`.  Putting the operator on the front of the list yields `["Add", "    Num 3", "    Num 3"]`, then joining them with `intercalate` produces `"Add\n    Num 3\n    Num 5"`.

---

The only remaining boilerplate is in the `case` expression. I think it's possible to eliminate that, but it requires a level of generic programming I'm not familiar with. I'm sure someone else could probably run with my answer to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when addressing duplication in code, it pays to keep the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)) in mind. Two occurrences of a block of code isn't necessarily a problem.

That said, Haskell is a (very) strongly-typed language, so you generally can't pattern-match on arity like you can in, say, Erlang or Clojure.

If you really want to abstract away the recursion part of a recursive data structure, you can define the **catamorphism** for it. People often also call this a **fold**, so let's keep that slightly more friendly name:

```
data Expr =
  Num Int | Add Expr Expr | Mult Expr Expr | Neg Expr | If Bool Expr Expr deriving (Show, Read)

foldExpr ::
  (Int -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> (Bool -> a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> a
foldExpr num   _   _   _   _ (Num x) = num x
foldExpr num add mul neg iff (Add x y) = 
  add (foldExpr num add mul neg iff x) (foldExpr num add mul neg iff y)
foldExpr num add mul neg iff (Mult x y) =
  mul (foldExpr num add mul neg iff x) (foldExpr num add mul neg iff y)
foldExpr num add mul neg iff (Neg x) = neg (foldExpr num add mul neg iff x)
foldExpr num add mul neg iff (If b x y) =
  iff b (foldExpr num add mul neg iff x) (foldExpr num add mul neg iff y)
```

This is an entirely generic function that enables you turn turn any `Expr` value into any value of the type `a`, without worrying about reimplementing recursion every time. You just have to supply functions that deal with each of the cases.

You can, for example, easily write an evaluator:

```
evaluate :: Expr -> Int
evaluate = foldExpr id (+) (*) negate (\p x y -> if p then x else y)
```

(Notice, BTW, that I changed the definition of `If`, because I couldn't see how the OP definition would work.)

You can also write a function to turn an `Expr` value into a string, although this one is **just a sketch**; it needs indentation or bracket logic to work correctly:

```
prettyPrint :: Expr -> String
prettyPrint =
  foldExpr
    show -- Num
    (\x y -> x ++ "+" ++ y) -- Add
    (\x y -> x ++ "*" ++ y) -- Mult
    (\x -> "(-" ++ x ++ ")") -- Neg
    (\p x y -> "if " ++ show p ++ " then " ++ x ++ " else " ++ y) -- If
```

You can try it out in GHCi:

```
*Q53284410> evaluate (Num 42)
42
*Q53284410> evaluate (Add (Num 40) (Num 2))
42
*Q53284410> evaluate (Add (Mult (Num 4) (Num 10)) (Num 2))
42
*Q53284410> prettyPrint $ Num 42
"42"
*Q53284410> prettyPrint $ Mult (Num 6) (Num 7)
"6*7"
*Q53284410> prettyPrint $ Add (Mult (Num 2) (Num 3)) (Num 7)
"2*3+7"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just create a function to print list of Expr:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)

printExprList::[Expr]->Int->String->IO ()
printExprList exprs i desc  =  do 
    putStrLn $ concat (replicate i "    ") ++ desc
    forM_ (zip exprs [i..]) $ \(e, j)-> prettyPrint' e (j+1)
```

and then call it to print:

```
prettyPrint' :: Expr -> Int -> IO ()     
prettyPrint' (Add x y) i  = printExprList [x, y]    i "Add"
prettyPrint' (Mult x y) i = printExprList [x, y]    i "Mult"
prettyPrint' (Neg x) i    = printExprList [x]       i "Neg"
prettyPrint' (If x y z) i = printExprList [x, y, z] i "If"

prettyPrint' (Num x) i = putStrLn $ concat (replicate i "    ") 
                         ++ "Num " ++ show x
```